# IntelliJ theme: customize bg-color of editor tab's close button

Tags: intellij-idea, themes, skin

I maintain an IntelliJ theme (Darcula Sombre), and latest build of IntelliJ 2020.1 introduced a grey background color in editor tab's close button (the gray circle).

[image: screenshot of the close button]

Do you know the property I should override?
I enabled Internals (add "idea.is.internal=true" to idea.properties) then looked at Tools > Internal Actions > UI > LaF Defaults, but found no useful property. Tested on IntelliJ 2020.1 EAP, Community edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customise it with "Actions.GreyInline" and "Actions.GreyInline.Dark" properties.

[image]